# How to get tag name from node with starts-with() function?

Tags: javascript, xpath

How to get tag name from nodes?

```
<h2 data-my-color="#333"></h2>
<div data-my-color="#222"></div>
<div data-my-color="#111"></div>
```

So I want to get 'h2', 'div', 'div'.

```
var nodeMy = document.evaluate('//@*[starts-with(name(), "data-my-")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var thisnodeMy = nodeMy.iterateNext();

while (thisnodeMy) {

    console.log(thisnodeMy);

    console.log(thisnodeMy.ownerElement.localName);/* Works... the good way?! */

    thisnodeMy = nodeMy.iterateNext(); 

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be element.nodeName

Comment: @Asutosh element.nodeName returns 'data-ym-color'...

Comment: That should only happen if the node is `<data-my-color ...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine but can be simplified a bit like this:

```js
var result = document.evaluate('//*[starts-with(name(@*), "data-my-")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var node = null;
var tagNames = [];
while(node = result.iterateNext()) {
  tagNames.push(node.nodeName);
}
console.log(tagNames.join(", "));
```

```html
<h2 data-my-color="#333"></h2>
<div data-my-color="#222"></div>
<div data-my-color="#111"></div>
```